# Magento 2 How to get all customer shipping address

Tags: magento2, database, customer, jquery, customer-address

How do get all customer shipping address?

Magento 2.3.5-p1 version

for the customer table, we can use - customer_entity table name

for the customer address table, we can use - customer_address_entity table name

On customer_entity we can see there is a column of default_billing and default_shipping but that column has a specific address id for this I am unable to find out all customer shipping address only.

Note: Need to just check from the database, not from code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `customer_address_entity` table may be what you are looking for.
It has all the address fields such as street, city, country, etc...

Comment: i just want to get only shipping address for all customers

Comment: Were you able to check the table I mentioned? In there exists all the shipping addresses. You can join using the `default_shipping_address` field in the `customer_entity` table in order to filter out billing addresses

Comment: shipping address exist and what is here default_shipping_address?

Comment: Apologies, the field name in `customer_entity` is actually just `default_shipping` which is a `customer_address_entity`.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the default shipping address for all customers

```
    SELECT 
        c.entity_id,
        c.email,
        e.*
    FROM 
        customer_entity c 
    INNER JOIN
        customer_address_entity e 
    ON 
        c.default_shipping = e.entity_id;
```

This will return the addresses that were used at least once on a customer order.

```
SELECT 
    c.entity_id,
    c.email,
    sa.*
FROM 
    customer_entity c 
INNER JOIN
    sales_order s
ON
    c.entity_id = s.customer_id
INNER JOIN
    sales_order_address sa
ON
    s.entity_id = sa.parent_id AND
    s.shipping_address_id = sa.entity_id;
```

Let me know if you need any further help !

Comment: ok i am checking ant let you know soon

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional help :) Don't forget to upvote / mark as answer if this solved your issue !